# C# class used only in refer projects inspection?

Tags: c#, class, reference, project, solution

Take a look at following solution:

```
MySolution.sln
   MyApp.csproj
   MyClassLib.csproj
      MyClass.cs
```

`MyClassLib` project referenced by `MyApp` project and contains `MyClass`. 
`MyClass` is used only in `MyApp`, so it can be moved there.

Is there a way to determine such cases with some tool? Maybe Roslyn or Resharper inspections?
In case of complex solution with long history and many projects this is required feature.

Comment: "MyClass is used only in MyApp, so it can be moved there." You should not (only) refactor classes where they are **used**, but rather where they **logically belong to**. It makes totally sense to have some class in one assembly while only one other assembly uses that type.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, I believe this refactoring leads to better logical structure of solution.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such tool for this.

Why? Easy: What if, sometime in the future, you create a `MyApp2` and that also needs `MyClass`? Then it would be better if `MyClass` is not in the `MyApp` assembly.

Now you, as the human developing this, might know that there will never (although never say never) be a `MyApp2` but a tool cannot possibly know this.

Comment: Okay, if I create a public property that is used only in containing class the tool offers me to make it private. It never knows if it will be used from outside in the future but still offers to do this. I see an analogy with classes in projects here.

Comment: @AsValeO This is just a hint, you don´t **have** to do it. No tool can indicate if that suggestion actually makes *sense logically*, but just *syntactically*. So don´t refactor all your code only because a tool suggest you so.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, then I need just a hint to move a class to another project.  This is useful in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I have limited experience with ReSharper, but from my experience, ReSharper can **not** automatically detect these cases where a file can be moved, but can visualize these hierarchies.

Going back to your earlier example, the hierarchy tool would show that your MyClass.cs file is only used by a file in MyApp.csproj. (It would not explicitly say this, but you would be able to tell based on the hierarchy.)

Answer (score 2):

You can either use CodeLens in visual studio to check where is used

[image: img]

or either right click on the class (or shift+f12) to "Find all references" and check where is used. This gives you a quick overview, give that you know your project structure, of the need of moving a class to some other place.

or use

[Code analysis tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/visualstudio/code-quality/code-analysis-for-managed-code-overview?view=vs-2019) or [other code tools](https://www.infoq.com/articles/redundant-code/) to check redundancy etc.

You cannot determine those automatically unless you fiddle with these tools, as it's an edge case when yourself know wheter a class should be placed in some place or not and no AI can replace that, unless you write your own custom code analysis tool that does that particular task.

Edit: Since author seems so much driven and determined into digging into this problem, I suggest you to take a shot into [T4 code generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019), [DSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/generating-code-from-a-domain-specific-language?view=vs-2019), [CodeDOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/using-the-codedom) to check if you can actually generate or analyze the code you want

Or, create [Custom code analysis rulesets](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/codeanalysis/2010/03/26/how-to-write-custom-static-code-analysis-rules-and-integrate-them-into-visual-studio-2010/) or check if the ones [already present](https://roslyn-analyzers.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config-analyzer.html) suits for you

Comment: Almost there, CodeLens gives all required info. I'm looking the way to automate this, or I should review each class manually. But they are billions..)

Answer (score 1):

@MindSwipe is right. However, if you really need to do this then here's a hack:

1. ensure your solution is under version control. this can help later.
2. select project `MyClassLib` and run a find and replace in all files of the current project: `public class` with `internal class`.
3. build your solution to get a bunch of errors
4. open the `ErrorList` pane and sort it by Description

You should see error messages such as: 
`The type or namespace name 'MyClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`.

If you see exactly 1 message per class then it means that class can be moved from the library project to the project that yielded this error. Otherwise it means it is shared by at least 2 projects; in this case you have to make it public again (undo the change made by the global replace for this class).